# SQL Server Report Builder (2016) - disabling page breaking within row group instance

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

I am working with SQL Server Report Builder 2016 to create a report and then export its contents to PDF. I have the following problem:

Tablix that forms a row group is filled with data from the dataset. There is a group property enabling setting page breaks between each instance of a group. What I want to achieve is - "**do not set page breaks within an instance of a group**", so that each page contains the maximum number of **complete** group instances.
At the moment page breaks are inserted in such a way that group instance can be split across two pages. Setting page break after each instance of a group is not the resolution of my issue as then, I would have just one group instance per page and I want to have as many groups as possible per page.

Could you please advise how to achieve that?
Maybe it would be possible to change the report structure, so that each group instance is exported as a separate table. Then, setting 'Keep together' option would give the desired outcome. At the moment all group instances are exported as one big table (multiple pages) and thus, 'Keep together' option does not make sense.

Thanks in advance!